# Hiding installed software via GPO

Tags: microsoft-office, group-policy

I'm wondering if it's possible to restrict certain groups from being able to see if software is installed. We distribute Microsoft Office licenses via AD group, and would like users that are only licensed to use the web app versions of the various office products to be unable to see the installed version. We don't want to simply blacklist the software, as that will mess with file associations and would generally be confusing for the end user. Ideally the machine appears as if no office products are installed at all for these users.

I had a bit of a look online and in the Policy Editor but wasn't able to work out if this is possible, or how one would go about it.

Comment: I'm thinking there are two parts to this, and GP doesn't likely have the actual solution, but scripts and security groups may. You'll need to set a security controlling access and no-access permissions on the application directories, and then you'll need a script that removes and adds the start menu and/or desktop shortcuts based on membership in the security group. The security groups on the application directories will be necessary to prevent people from just navigating to the application directories and creating their own shortcuts.

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean the silent installation? Refer this link: https://silentinstallhq.com/microsoft-office-365-silent-install-how-to-guide/

Comment: OP doesn't appear to be asking how to install the software, but how to control user's access to the software using domain management tools such as AD and GPOs.